# Scottish flag doesn't work on my page, other Emoji 5 do, though

Tags: php, html, emoji

I'm generating my webpage using PHP, calling `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning.

The Scottish flag emoji renders as a black flag, as if it was missing (*it does so here too, by the way*).

However:

- other Emoji 5 work instead, i.e.
- it **does work on other sites**, such as [here](https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-scotland/)
- if I look at the page's source code as displayed by the browser… **it does work**
- other flags work

So, giving that it *does* work on other sites, it's definitely not browser's fault by my page's… but for the life of me I can't figure out what I did wrong, where.

Is it a problem in PHP, in the generated HTML, in the CSS files, in the Apache server? I don't even know where to investigate.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: _“How can I fix this problem?”_ - by first of all properly _describing_ it ... so far I am not really sure what your actual issue is. At least show your live site as well, so that we can compare what is actually different between that, and your working example elsewhere.

Comment: _“it does work on other sites, such as [here](https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-scotland/)”_ - that shows _exactly_ the same black flag symbol for me in Chrome, as it also does here in your question. Therefor, still ... whatchuonabout?

Comment: @CBroe I may have missed something, but I definitely described the issue. The flag should show, it doesn't. You are just nitpicking for the sake of it. Quit that BOFH behaviour, it's harmful for yourself and definitely for people around you.

Comment: _“The flag should show, it doesn't.”_ - you have not backed that up with any actual example that would allow us to determine whether _you_ simply might have messed things up somehow. Therefor, you have basically told us that there _is_ a problem, but given us about zero _useful_ information about it. Plus, even the example you said worked doesn’t, at least not for me, in my browser - so without any futher explanation from you as to what specific conditions (browser, fonts, ...) might need to be given, even this doesn’t make your question any more clear, but on the contrary.

Comment: @CBroe do you realise you are still aggressive and confrontational? Stop that, please.

Comment: What if wasting everyone’s time with sub-standard problem descriptions was “aggressive and confrontational” from my point of view ...? _“Is it a problem in PHP, in the generated HTML, in the CSS files, in the Apache server?”_  - well if you don’t have a clue where the problem might perhaps lie to begin with, then how could we even possibly, with the amount of info you have given us so far...? You have the rest of the code in front of you, whereas we have - what exactly? (Basically the info that your Content-Type header says UTF-8 - great ...)

Answer (score 0):

I think that scottish flag is a sequence of symbols:

```
U+1F3F4
U+E0067
U+E0062
U+E0073
U+E0063
U+E0074
U+E007F
```

ref: https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-scotland/

Comment: Sure, but still I should be able to just paste it in the page and it should just work, like it _does_ elsewhere…

Comment: Plus, AFAIK other flags are a sequence of symbols too, and they do work.